# dist folder content works only on the root of the server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

For the following github project:
https://github.com/miyaoka/grid-generator.git

I am running `yarn install` and then `npm run generate` commands.

And then I am taking all of the content of the dist folder and putting the content of the dist folder inside htdocs in xampp, but then I am getting a lot of `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` from the console.

But when I am taking the content of the dist folder and putting this directly on the root of htdocs (directly inside htdocs not within any folder) everything is working fine.

What should I add inside nuxt.config.js? And where exactly inside nuxt.config.js? In order to be able to run the project from a folder inside htdocs?

And after I will update nuxt.config.js which command/s I need to run again?

nuxt.config.js file:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  modules: ['~/modules/typescript'],
  plugins: ['~plugins/vue-awesome.js'],

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: 'CSS Grid Layout generator',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    vendor: ['vue-awesome'],
    /*
    ** Run ESLint on save
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.dev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
      if (ctx.isServer) {
        config.externals = [
          nodeExternals({
            // default value for `whitelist` is
            // [/es6-promise|\.(?!(?:js|json)$).{1,5}$/i]
            whitelist: [/es6-promise|\.(?!(?:js|json)$).{1,5}$/i, /^vue-awesome/]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [router.base](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base)

```
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/app/'
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to add this code inside nuxt.config.js? And if yes, where exactly?

Comment: yes in nuxt config. See link to the docs that i linked its pretty self explaining

Comment: I tried to add it and run only the "npm run generate" command again. But still the same problem..